# Convert query result to array

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can convert result from query to array. For example

```
select ARRAY[x."Id"] as "id"
from public."jp_OnlyIds" as x
```

In above code, I get many rows with single element array, I want to get one array with all element, how can I do this?

I use Posgres database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select array_agg(x."id")  as "id" from public."jp_OnlyIds" as x
```